# Sublime Text 3: Auto-Complete uses incorrect syntax for for loop

Tags: autocomplete, sublimetext3

With sublime text 3, the autocomplete when typing "for" and hitting tab gives you:

```
for x in xrange(1,10):
    pass
```

However, this is not a valid statement for python 3. I've tried creating a new build system using the following:

```
{
    "cmd": ["c:/Python37/python.exe", "-u", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python"
}
```

the auto-complete for for still gives the wrong syntax. any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short version is that the `sublime-build` and `sublime-snippet` files that ship with Sublime in support of Python target Python version 2 and not Python version 3. I don't know if that's just due to that being what was used initially or if it's being done on purpose, though.

In Sublime, resources are generally related to a particular language based on the `scope` provided by the syntax definition. So for example snippets for Python are associated with `source.python`, your example build file uses that scope to know that it applies to Python files, and so on. As such, no matter what build you happen to be using, that has no effect on the snippets that are being offered.

By way of example, if you use the `View Package File` command from the command palette and enter the text `python for snippet`, the list of package resources will filter to `Python/Snippets/for.sublime-snippet`; pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> to view that resource shows this:

```xml
<snippet>
    <tabTrigger>for</tabTrigger>
    <scope>source.python</scope>
    <description>For Loop</description>
    <content><![CDATA[
for ${1:x} in ${2:xrange(1,10)}:
    ${0:pass}
]]></content>
</snippet>
```

Here the `tabTrigger` specifies **how** the snippet inserts, `scope` controls **where** it inserts and `content` controls **what** it is inserts. Thus, in order to change it to support Python 3, you need to either create your own snippet or modify the existing one.

An issue with creating your own snippet is that it will be added to the list of snippets **including** the offending one, which allows it to possibly still trigger when you don't expect it to. There is also no general purposes "easy" way to disable individual snippets.

As such, generally the best course of action would be to use the [PackageResourceViewer](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PackageResourceViewer) package. Install it, select `PackageResourceViewer: Open Resource` from the command palette, then select the same file as outlined above and modify the content of the snippet (e.g. replace `xrange` with `range`) and save the file.

That will get Sublime to replace the existing snippet with your edited version, so that it takes the place of the existing one and works the way you want.

Comment: thank you for the incredibly clear and concise explanation that i just wasn't able to find anywhere else, even with my google fu. much appreciated!